# symbol \eth already defined when using libertinus(-otf) and lualatex [pandoc]

Tags: luatex, pandoc, libertine, libertinus

Using `libertinus` as fontfamily within a yaml-header of a `.md`-file and trying to convert with pandoc (2.9.2) and the pdf-engine `lualatex` (TL 2020, LuaLaTeX 1.12.0) I get the following error-message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\eth' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.240 ...mbol{\eth}            {\mathord}{AMSb}{"67}
```

**Steps to reproduce**
Take this mwe for the `.md`-file

```
---
title: Test
author: Author
date: \today
fontfamily: libertinus
---
This is a test-file. 

ÄÜÖß

1234567890
```

the command for the conversion is

```
pandoc -s libertinus-test.md --pdf-engine=lualatex -o libertinus-test.pdf
```

I figured out that the problem is the line with the math-packages:

https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/9d0506e4047f797a0672d7767830b59f1710d191/data/templates/default.latex#L100

**Note:**
As soon as I change the fontfamily to `libertine` it is no problem.
But same problem also occurs with `libertinus-otf` (by HV).

---

There is also an issue for this topic:
https://github.com/alif-type/libertinus/issues/327

Comment: You have to convince `pandoc` not to load `amssymb`.

Comment: and how can I do that *without* changing the default template?

Comment: Notify the `pandoc` people that loading `amssymb` along with `unicode-math` is nonsensical. As far as I can see, there is no conditional around `\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}` in the default template, so you're doomed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default `pandoc` template has

```
100 \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
101 \usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
102 \ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
103   \usepackage[$if(fontenc)$$fontenc$$else$T1$endif$]{fontenc}
104   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
105   \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
106 \else % if luatex or xetex
107 $if(mathspec)$
108   \ifxetex
109     \usepackage{mathspec}
110   \else
111     \usepackage{unicode-math}
112   \fi
113 $else$
114   \usepackage{unicode-math}
115 $endif$
```

which unconditionally loads `amssymb`. This is the cause of your issues.

Note that loading `amssymb` along with `unicode-math` makes very little sense (if at all).

A more sensible template would have

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[$if(fontenc)$$fontenc$$else$T1$endif$]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
  \usepackage{amssymb}
\else % if luatex or xetex
$if(mathspec)$
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \fi
$else$
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
$endif$
```

Comment: please have a look at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6469 and comment!

Comment: @lemzwerg Yes, there was an oversight, fixed my proposal.

Comment: "Note that loading amssymb along with unicode-math makes very little sense (if at all)" -- this seems to be wrong. See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6825 -- when we removed amssymb, it seems we lost `\square` which we need for todo lists.

Comment: @JohnMacFarlane Abusing a math symbol font for text parts is not the best strategy.

Comment: I'm not sure we can rely on the existence of appropriate glyphs in the main font -- since users can specify their own, and we don't know what fonts are available.  Do you have another suggestion?